# Complaint management system

Tags: crm

HI everyone,

I was asked to develop a complaint/suggestion management system, I was wondering if anybody has an idea about what features should be there, if there is an already made system that i can view its documentation to help that will be great

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My company uses [Web Help Desk](http://webhelpdesk.com/). It has a really nice interface and is really complete. One thing that you should keep in mind is that you should implement really nice printing CSS to get **good looking** hard copies of tickets. Your support team will love you for that :)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at google moderator for ideas:

http://www.google.com/moderator/

Answer (score 0):

How about [SalesForce](http://www.salesforce.com)?

Answer (score 0):

Record the number of complaints/suggestions made by an individual and display the total on each ticket. Frequent complainers can perhaps have a little less weight given to their complaints... frequent suggesters are obviously volunteering to implement suggestions :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also add the categorization mechanism to seep up the analysis. Then you be able to see how many people complained about a particular thing or how many people wish to have a particular feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Zendesk](http://www.zendesk.com/). IMO,it's the best customer service platform.